# Use total differential to approximate the quantity $ (1.92^2+2.2^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: calculus

Use total differential to approximate the quantity $ (1.92^2+2.2^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

**Answer:**
Let $ f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Now, $ (1.92^2+2.2^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}=\sqrt[3]{8.5264}$

Let $ x=8 , \ \Delta x=0.5264 \ \ and \ \ x+\Delta x=8.5264 $

$ So, \ \ f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x)+f'(x) \Delta x $,

or, $ f(8.5264) \approx f(8)+\frac{1}{3* \sqrt[3]{x^2}}|_{x=8} *(0.5264) $

or, $ \sqrt[3]{8.5264} \approx \sqrt[3]{8}+\frac{0.5264}{12} =2.0437 $

or, $ (1.92^2+2.2^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} \approx 2.0437 $.

If I calculate by calculator, then $ (1.92^2+2.2^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}=2.0429 $.

So both are almost equal.

**I need  confirmation of my work. Any help ?**

Comment: It seems to me that you are just using Taylor series truncated to first order. Well done !

Comment: The fact that you're calling this a total differential makes me think this is a question from a multivariable calculus course, in which case you should think of a function $f(x,y) = (x+y)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, and calculate the change by $f(a+h) = f(a) + \nabla f(a) \cdot h$. Of course this may not be the case and you're using the terminology for a single variable calculus class. Just choose the appropriate technique :)